# Strange jQuery error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, console

## Short

Getting

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object] @ jquery.js:4267
```

Here is piece of code from jQ

```
Sizzle.error = function( msg ) {
throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg ); // Line 4267
};
```

## Detailed

I have pre-declared array `aoData`. This array created by Datatables, and I have no contorl over array structure.

When I manually push params one-by-one like this:

`aoData.push( { "name": "process", "value": "fetch" } );`

it works well, without any error message.

But the problem is, when I try to declare array `tableXtraPostParams` at the top of script and push one by one this array's params into `aoData`, it still works fine, but getting strange error message not from my code but from jQuery.

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object] @ jquery.js:4267
```

Here is piece of code: (When I remove `$.each` loop it error message disappears)

```
var tableXtraPostParams = {
    "process":"fetch",
    "which":"mine"
};
$.each(tableXtraPostParams, function(n, v){
    aoData.push( {
       "name": n, 
       "value": v
    } );
});
```

Here is, what `aoData` looks like before push

```
[Object { name="sEcho", value=1}, Object { name="iColumns", value=8}, Object { name="sColumns", value=""}, Object { name="iDisplayStart", value=0}, Object { name="iDisplayLength", value=25}, Object { name="mDataProp_0", value=0}, Object { name="mDataProp_1", value=1}, Object { name="mDataProp_2", value=2}, Object { name="mDataProp_3", value=3}, Object { name="mDataProp_4", value=4}, Object { name="mDataProp_5", value=5}, Object { name="mDataProp_6", value=6}, Object { name="mDataProp_7", value=7}, Object { name="sSearch", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex", value=false}, Object { name="sSearch_0", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_0", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_0", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_1", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_1", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_1", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_2", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_2", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_2", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_3", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_3", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_3", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_4", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_4", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_4", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_5", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_5", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_5", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_6", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_6", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_6", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_7", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_7", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_7", value=true}, Object { name="iSortingCols", value=1}, Object { name="iSortCol_0", value=0}, Object { name="sSortDir_0", value="asc"}, Object { name="bSortable_0", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_1", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_2", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_3", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_4", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_5", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_6", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_7", value=true}]
```

And here is after push

```
[Object { name="sEcho", value=1}, Object { name="iColumns", value=8}, Object { name="sColumns", value=""}, Object { name="iDisplayStart", value=0}, Object { name="iDisplayLength", value=25}, Object { name="mDataProp_0", value=0}, Object { name="mDataProp_1", value=1}, Object { name="mDataProp_2", value=2}, Object { name="mDataProp_3", value=3}, Object { name="mDataProp_4", value=4}, Object { name="mDataProp_5", value=5}, Object { name="mDataProp_6", value=6}, Object { name="mDataProp_7", value=7}, Object { name="sSearch", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex", value=false}, Object { name="sSearch_0", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_0", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_0", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_1", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_1", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_1", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_2", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_2", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_2", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_3", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_3", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_3", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_4", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_4", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_4", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_5", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_5", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_5", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_6", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_6", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_6", value=true}, Object { name="sSearch_7", value=""}, Object { name="bRegex_7", value=false}, Object { name="bSearchable_7", value=true}, Object { name="iSortingCols", value=1}, Object { name="iSortCol_0", value=0}, Object { name="sSortDir_0", value="asc"}, Object { name="bSortable_0", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_1", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_2", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_3", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_4", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_5", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_6", value=true}, Object { name="bSortable_7", value=true}, Object { name="process", value="fetch"}, Object { name="which", value="all"}]
```

## What I tried to resolve

1. I downloaded jQ 1.7.2 (dev edition) and replaced with minified 1.7.2. No success!
2. I tried to write

.

```
for( var p in tableXtraPostParams ) {
    aoData.push( {
       "name": p,
       "value": tableXtraPostParams[p]
    } );
}
```

instead of $.each. No success!

What am I missing here? I have really no idea, why this error message appears in Firefox log, when I try to push from inside $.each and code still works perfectly.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Note

Here is one by one version (without $.each): datatables.net/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html

Comment: I made a simple JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/brantolsen/GkWzN/, using your code and everything seemed to work. Can you please try to replicate the error in the JSFiddle? Note that I tried both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @BrantOlsen the problem is aodata is already declaared, and I have no control over it's structure. Worry but I have no control over it's structure. Here is working example. http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/pipeline.html I'm trying to push other parameters into this array based on this http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html

Comment: Why are you getting a jQuery error when you're not using jQuery in the code posted under _tried to resolve_ heading? Are you sure you're looking at the right place? Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @SalmanA `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object] @ jquery.js:4267` error that I'm getting is inside jQ

Answer (score 1):

I expect you are looking in the wrong place for that error. If the object and array you are iterating on and augmenting are NOT jQuery instances, and you can reproduce it without using $.each, I think you should look at what you do with aoData later.

Sizzle is the selector engine, so look for a place where you do something like this:

```
$(aoData[0])
```

In this hypothetical case, you are making jQuery think it has a selector, but you have handed it something else.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thx for trying to help. See my comment under question